Moviepy not updating FFmpeg Version after FFmpeg Install?
I've been toying around with MoviePy, and recently switched a project to a new computer at home to continue messing around with it. However, I tried running what I had previously written (which ran perfectly fine on the other computer) and I get this:
OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file ./Gameplay/minecraft-
gameplay2.mp4. That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that you are using 
a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is 
deprecated. Please update to a recent version from the website.


After reading the error, I did as it instructed, and updated my FFmpeg:
$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-115387-g8e27bd025f-20240525 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.26.0.65_ecc5e41)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-openssl --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --enable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --enable-libxcb --enable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libdvdread --enable-libdvdnav --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --disable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs='-ldl -lgomp' --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags=-pie --cc=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu-gcc --cxx=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu-g++ --ar=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu-gcc-ar --ranlib=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib --nm=x86_64-ffbuild-linux-gnu-gcc-nm --extra-version=20240525
  libavutil      59. 20.100 / 59. 20.100
  libavcodec     61.  5.104 / 61.  5.104
  libavformat    61.  3.104 / 61.  3.104
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Universal media converter
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

And I continued getting the same error. So I looked at what version my moviepy was using, and it was still 4.X. I read somewhere that your FFmpeg version is determined on the first use, which made sense, so I uninstalled and reinstalled, to get the same error.
I am honestly lost at this point, as I have the newest version of FFmpeg, but I still get this from moviepy:
>>> import moviepy
>>> print(moviepy.config.FFPMEG_BINARY)
ffmpeg : /home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imageio_ffmpeg/binaries/ffmpeg-linux64-v4.2.2

Any Ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
(Note: I'm using Crostini which I believe is using an Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Like shell)
Thanks :)

The message tells you what's wrong: the binary isn't your system copy of ffmpeg but a separate executable under your home directory (which from a security perspective is... not good practice, as whatever downloaded and installed that binary isn't subject to your distro's QA, code signing, and similar measures).

That is to say, if you run ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imageio_ffmpeg/binaries/ffmpeg-linux64-v4.2.2 --version, you'll see the version string regarding the old version.

@CharlesDuffy Thanks? That's great information.. but that's not quite what I'm asking, I'm trying to get the MoviePy FFmpeg version to update, I have my System's FFmpeg version updated

Right, but unless MoviePy absolutely requires you to use the binaries it bundles, I'd just not do that at all (and honestly, if it didn't work except with its own binaries, I'd call that adequate reasoning to not use MoviePy). Modify moviepy.config.FFMPEG_BINARY to point at the OS-vendor-provided executable and as long as it's compatible enough that the library can support it, there you are.

(By "modify", I don't mean "change the library source", I mean run the code moviepy.config.FFMPEG_BINARY = shutil.which("ffmpeg") after import moviepy but before doing anything else with moviepy).

@CharlesDuffy would I have to do that every time I use MoviePy (which I'd be fine with, it'd just be a single script) or would I just need to do it once?

This would be something that goes in your script so it happens every time.

@CharlesDuffy Thanks for the help, however I'm still getting the same OSError, (and yes, I checked, the video is not corrupted.

I wasn't proposing that as a fix to the OSError, I was proposing it as a fix to the wrong version being used. Does it fix that?

The wrong version was causing the OSError...

The error message claims that, but high-level error messages aren't always accurate. This isn't a real OSError direct from the Python interpreter itself, it's one MoviePy is synthesizing.

Once you have installed it, ImageMagick should be automatically detected by MoviePy, except for some developers under specific OS:
for windows users, you may also set the variable IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY from the moviepy config file. To avoid doing so, make sure to check "install legacy utilities" in the installation wizard.
for ubuntu users (≥ 19.04), you may have installed from apt://imagemagick (or via the apt install command line), then you need to disable this line  from the security policy file located at /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml.
MoviePy additionally depends on the Python modules Numpy, imageio, Decorator, and tqdm, which will be automatically installed during MoviePy’s installation but it also needs extra common libraries like PIL, FFMPEG for specific usecases...
Tell me if it helped (not so sure)

Thanks for the info, however that doesn't really solve my problem..

I see the moviePy config seems well formed, also I assume your file isn't corrupted, maybe it's about permissions, have you tried this ? Ensure that your script has the necessary permissions to read the video file and access the FFmpeg binary.
